# how to get the latest record from MySQL Server database for a particular condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with the fields as described in the simplified example below.

What does the sql query look like for getting the latest record for a particular type value (say type value = 4, see example)?

```
id - type -   details   - created
 1     4     'detailsA'   2010-09-07
 2     4     'detailsB'   2010-09-10   //this is the record to be retrieved
 3     3     'detailsC'   2010-09-14
```

The only way I see is by means of 2 queries; the first query retrieving the related date (2010-09-10) by means of MAX(date), and use that value in the second query...

Comment: How you are identifying that its latest record ? By Date or by last entry (The date can be any thing)

Comment: By date; 'created' is of type DATE

Comment: If more than one record has inserted on same date , then you need to use the ID for desc order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, type, details, created
from MyTable
where type = 4
order by created desc
limit 1
```

Comment: thnx (!). Just curious about how this works under the hood?: does the query results in a (possibly) long list which is then filtered to one item?

Comment: Yes, it must order by all records where type=4, so that it can then select the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
select id, type, details, created
from MyTable
where type = 4
order by created desc
limit 0,1;
```

Or

If on same date more than one record has entered then, you can use below query.

```
 select id, type, details, created
    from MyTable
    where type = 4
    order by id desc
    limit 0,1;
```